# Resultant entropy of the target feature example

Tags: decision-trees

I'm confused by an example I have come across on entropy.

In a decision tree, we have after a split on some particular feature, the following subset of our training data.  What is the resultant entropy of the target feature in this set?

[image]

I thought for feature A the result would be:

-65/121(log2(65/121)-56/121 log2(56/121)

But that doesn't match the answer provided.

Comment: The resultant entropy of the 'target feature' would be $-\frac{3}{5} \log_2(\frac{3}{5}) -\frac{2}{5} \log_2(\frac{2}{5}) = 0.97095...$.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. Is it just True over False?

So it's -2/5...?